# Android stopService() in AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

Hi I am developing an App and I need to put my stopService(); in PositiveButton in AlertDialog.Builder but I get a error , My code is :

.... Other Code

```
.setPositiveButton("Yes",newDialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id)
   {                                                                        

     finish();
     System.exit(0);                                    
     stopService(new Intent(this, Service.class));
  }
}
```

.... Other Code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please go through the posting rules on this site. Also please post your logcat for this question and provide as much info as possible for your error, or your question will be downvoted

Comment: you should remove this `System.exit(0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id)
   {                                                                        

       stopService(new Intent(<InsertYourActivityClassName>.this, Service.class));
       finish();                               

  }
```

Comment: Edited, change `this` to `<youractivityclassname>.this`